# Unable to persist 'posts' reference for 'users' in Firebase

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase

I'm creating a social app and a common aspect of it is keeping tabs of the posts that users make. I'm using Firebase as the backend for this and here's my schema

```
SocialApp
 posts
   -KGsBG5TPYBtzRivZnbf

   users
     facebook:10154108240254134
      cachedProfile
      displayName: "Karthik Kannan"
      imageURL: "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100..."
      posts
         -KGsBG5TPYBtzRivZnbf: true
      provider: "facebook"
```

When i go ahead and add posts from one device(or simulator) this works as planned but when i delete the app from a device and reinstall it, the posts relationship in the users dictionary disappears. I would like it to persist across devices and keep the relationship intact so if a user decides to use another iDevice to login his posts don't get orphaned.
Here's the code I wrote for adding a post to Firebase and how I currently keep track of the user.

```
func postToFirebase(imgUrl: String) {
    var gift: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "giftName": giftName.text!,
        "giftDescription":giftDescription.text!,
        "giftAvailableAt": giftAvailableAt.text!,
        "giftPrice": Int(giftPrice.text!)!,
        "username": NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid")!,
        "giftImage":imgUrl,
    ]

    let firebasePost = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId()
    firebasePost.setValue(gift)

    firebasePost.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let postID = snapshot.key {
            DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.childByAppendingPath("posts").childByAppendingPath(postID).setValue(true)
        }

    })
    }
```

This is how I set current users:

```
var REF_USER_CURRENT:Firebase {
    if let uid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as? String {

        let user = Firebase(url:"\(BASE_URL)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(did){
           return user!
        } else {
            return Firebase()
        }
    }

    func createFirebaseUser(uid:String, user:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

        REF_USERS.childByAppendingPath(uid).setValue(user)
    }
```

And this is the code in my login controller.

```
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")

       let user = ["provider":authData.provider!,"displayName":authData.providerData["displayName"]!,"cachedProfile":authData.providerData["cachedUserProfile"]!, "imageURL":authData.providerData["profileImageURL"]!]

       DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(authData.uid, user: user)

       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: nil)
```

This is all the code I've written. I suspect it's something to do with NSUserDefaults. Any help would be greatly appreciated by this beginner.

Comment: When you write a post to Firebase, did you log into your Firebase dashboard and ensure the data was actually there. Second, have you attached any onDisconnect observers to any nodes in your Firebase. And finally, when the user logs out or disconnects to you write anything to Firebase? And... in the login controller, why are your createFirebaseUser when it should be used to authenticate an existing user.

Comment: Where do you actually authenticate your user? Also, just to clarify, data doesn't persist across devices; data exists in Firebase and Firebase enables and synchronizes data across the devices that observe Firebase data.

Comment: hey @Jay, I've logged into the dashboard and checked the presence of the data. It's only the relationship between the user and the post that has been "reset". And my createFirebaseUser isnt in the login controller but in a separate file that I use for Firebase Data Services.

Comment: I authenticate my user in the Login Controller. Check if he's already is logged in or else open up the login screen.

Comment: There's really only two ways for the data to be removed from Firebase 1) if there is an onDisconnect observer attached to that node (or a parent) and 2) If the data is set to nil. My guess is the latter, so maybe when quitting the app or perhaps when logging in the next time, that node is being set to nil which will remove it from Firebase. You can kind of test that; start up your app and login. Then open your Firebase dashboard. Make sure there data in question appears in the Dashboard. Then quit the app. If you see the data vanish in the Dashboard, then it's likely being set to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code. I found a typo here:

> var REF_USER_CURRENT:Firebase {
>       if let uid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as? String {
>
> ```
>     let user = Firebase(url:"\(BASE_URL)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(did){
>        return user!
>     } else {
>         return Firebase()
>     }
> }
> ```

Instead of "...childByAppendingPath(did)"
You might want to change "did" to "uid"

Other than that, I have not tested out the rest of your code.

Seems like You have watched the Mark Price course, for making this app.
So have I :)